# How to create sequence number in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I expects the numbers in the red circle but i gets what is left of the red circle. So gets **6** where i expects **2** and **11** where i expects **3**.
for that you can refer first image.

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(cmb_Type.Value)

Dim lr As Long
lr = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("A:A"))

sh.Range("A" & lr + 1).Value = lr
sh.Range("B" & lr + 1).Value = Me.txt_Date.Value
sh.Range("C" & lr + 1).Value = Me.cmb_Type.Value
sh.Range("D" & lr + 1).Value = Left(Me.cmb_Type.Value, 2) & lr
sh.Range("E" & lr + 1).Value = Me.cmb_Party.Value
sh.Range("F" & lr + 1).Value = Me.cmb_Category.Value
sh.Range("G" & lr + 1).Value = Me.cmb_Product.Value
sh.Range("H" & lr + 1).Value = Me.txt_Qty.Value
sh.Range("I" & lr + 1).Value = Me.txt_Rate.Value

sh.Range("A" & lr + 2).Value = lr
sh.Range("B" & lr + 2).Value = Me.txt_Date.Value
sh.Range("C" & lr + 2).Value = Me.cmb_Type.Value
sh.Range("D" & lr + 2).Value = Left(Me.cmb_Type.Value, 2) & lr
sh.Range("E" & lr + 2).Value = Me.cmb_Party.Value
sh.Range("F" & lr + 2).Value = Me.cmb_Category1.Value
sh.Range("G" & lr + 2).Value = Me.cmb_Product1.Value
sh.Range("H" & lr + 2).Value = Me.txt_Qty1.Value
sh.Range("I" & lr + 2).Value = Me.txt_Rate1.Value

sh.Range("A" & lr + 3).Value = lr
sh.Range("B" & lr + 3).Value = Me.txt_Date.Value
sh.Range("C" & lr + 3).Value = Me.cmb_Type.Value
sh.Range("D" & lr + 3).Value = Left(Me.cmb_Type.Value, 2) & lr
sh.Range("E" & lr + 3).Value = Me.cmb_Party.Value
sh.Range("F" & lr + 3).Value = Me.cmb_Category2.Value
sh.Range("G" & lr + 3).Value = Me.cmb_Product2.Value
sh.Range("H" & lr + 3).Value = Me.txt_Qty2.Value
sh.Range("I" & lr + 3).Value = Me.txt_Rate2.Value
```

[Input Userform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcMSF.jpg)
[Output sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EzaH.jpg)

Comment: [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) please include it as text formatted as code block. Please also explain how to find out which rows get the same numbers? Why do the first 5 rows have the same serial? What's the criteria for that?

Comment: "not working" is not helpful. What error message do you get?

Comment: @StureS there is no error, he just dosen't get what he expects to get. He expects the numbers in the red circle but he gets what is left of the red circel. So he gets `6` where he expects `2` and `11` where he expects `3`.

Comment: @PEH  yes, you got my problem

Comment: Is that 6 & 2, 11 & 3 in the same column separated by a space or something?  Both values appear to be in column B?  But the code says that column B gets it value from `Me.txt_Date.Value` which sounds like a date, but that appears in column C.  I'm confused...

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook please refer updated output sheet

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook i want number sequence start from 2 instead of 6 and 3 instead of 11 and ....so on

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, because your question is a but unclear but try the following:

Add the code below right below your `lr = Application.…` line.

```
Dim SerialNumber As Long
SerialNumber = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(sh.Columns("A")) + 1
```

And instead of where you have `.Value = lr` you should write

```
.Value = SerialNumber
```

Because `lr` is the last row that is why you get a `6` where you expect a `2` because the amount of rows is `6` there. What you want is the maximum number of your serial column `+ 1`.

Comment: Have made changes in my problem, please refer again?

Comment: @RahulNadola have you tried what I wrote above?

Comment: code is working but, not get sequence as i mentioned in image

Comment: @PEH i tried with your last solutions but, '.Max(sh.Columns("A")) + 1' replaced with above sequence number

Comment: @RahulNadola I don't understand what you did exactly and what the problem is. Please be more precise. You can append information to your original question if comments are not enough to explain properly.